# Tweepy reply to mentions bot

Tags: python, tweepy

When I run this script to reply to Twitter mentions with Tweepy I keep getting the error NameError: name 'create_api' is not defined and I am not sure why. What am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
import tweepy
import logging
import time

def create_api():
    consumer_key = 'xxxxx'
    consumer_secret = 'xxxxx'
    access_token = 'xxxx-xxxx'
    access_token_secret = 'xxxx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, 
wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
try:
    api.verify_credentials()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Error creating API", exc_info=True)
        raise e
    logger.info("API created")
    return api

def check_mentions(api, keywords, since_id):
    logger.info("Retrieving mentions")
    new_since_id = since_id
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.mentions_timeline,
        since_id=since_id).items():
        new_since_id = max(tweet.id, new_since_id)
        if tweet.in_reply_to_status_id is not None:
            continue
        if any(keyword in tweet.text.lower() for keyword in keywords):
            logger.info(f"Answering to {tweet.user.name}")

            if not tweet.user.following:
                tweet.user.follow()

            api.update_status(
                status="Please reach us via DM",
                in_reply_to_status_id=tweet.id,
            )
    return new_since_id

def main():
    api = create_api()
    since_id = 1
    while True:
        since_id = check_mentions(api, ["help", "support"], since_id)
        logger.info("Waiting...")
        time.sleep(60)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What's the full traceback? You have indentation issues.

Comment: I can't replicate this. Your indentation formatting is incorrect, and after fixing those issues for myself, I'm getting the error ```tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 89, 'message': 'Invalid or expired token.'}]```, which means I'm able to go into the ```create_api()``` function.

Comment: I'm also getting this error ```NameError: name 'logger' is not defined``` which you should probably look into.

Comment: @LapisRose can you show me what you did exactly? Because I thought I did it and now I'm getting other errors. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Harmon758 now the error is different. , line 17
    except exception as e:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: All I did was fix indentation issues.

Comment: As I said, you have indentation issues. [Indentation is Python’s way of grouping statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming).

Comment: Your title is not reflecting the real issue. Please consider re-write it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that most of your errors come from improper indentation. Here is the version of your code where I fixed the indentation issues.

I get `NameError: name 'logger' is not defined` because the proper method of using the `logging` library is to use `logging.x` instead of `logger`. This seems to be a small typo.

After fixing that, I get `tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 89, 'message': 'Invalid or expired token.'}]`, which is to be expected because I don't have a valid token.

```
import tweepy
import logging
import time

def create_api():
    consumer_key = 'xxxxx'
    consumer_secret = 'xxxxx'
    access_token = 'xxxx-xxxx'
    access_token_secret = 'xxxx'

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, 
    wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
    try:
        api.verify_credentials()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Error creating API", exc_info=True)
        raise e
    logging.info("API created")
    return api

def check_mentions(api, keywords, since_id):
    logging.info("Retrieving mentions")
    new_since_id = since_id
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.mentions_timeline,
        since_id=since_id).items():
        new_since_id = max(tweet.id, new_since_id)
        if tweet.in_reply_to_status_id is not None:
            continue
        if any(keyword in tweet.text.lower() for keyword in keywords):
            logging.info(f"Answering to {tweet.user.name}")

            if not tweet.user.following:
                tweet.user.follow()

            api.update_status(
                status="Please reach us via DM",
                in_reply_to_status_id=tweet.id,
            )
    return new_since_id

def main():
    api = create_api()
    since_id = 1
    while True:
        since_id = check_mentions(api, ["help", "support"], since_id)
        logging.info("Waiting...")
        time.sleep(60)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output:** (to show that the logging is catching the error)

```
ERROR:root:Error creating API
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\stack15.py", line 16, in create_api
    api.verify_credentials()
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\source\repos\PyProjects\py_3.7\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 605, in verify_credentials
    )(**kargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\source\repos\PyProjects\py_3.7\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 250, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\source\repos\PyProjects\py_3.7\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 233, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 89, 'message': 'Invalid or expired token.'}]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\stack15.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\stack15.py", line 44, in main
    api = create_api()
  File ".\stack15.py", line 19, in create_api
    raise e
  File ".\stack15.py", line 16, in create_api
    api.verify_credentials()
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\source\repos\PyProjects\py_3.7\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 605, in verify_credentials
    )(**kargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\source\repos\PyProjects\py_3.7\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 250, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\source\repos\PyProjects\py_3.7\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 233, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 89, 'message': 'Invalid or expired token.'}]
```

Comment: that did it! I had a phantom space my IDE didn't pick up. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

When you reply, use tweet.id_str rather that tweet.id